# Reverse relationships for accessing user's profile

Tags: python, django

In my app, there are users with 0 or 1 profile at the same time.
Over the time, I project to have many different profiles.

Accessing user from profileX is easy : `profile_x_object.user`
But what about the reverse relation? 
I'd like to find the best generic way to create a relation from user to its profile.

For now, I created a property named `profile` to fill that purpose.
It works but it need to be updated foreach new profile I add over time.
Any idea to do better?

Here is the code I have:

```
class User:
   # ...

    @property
    def profile(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'profilea'):
            return self.profilea
        if hasattr(self, 'probileb'):
            return self.probileb

class BaseProfile(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class ProfileA(BaseProfile, models.Model):
    # ...

class ProfileB(BaseProfile, models.Model):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [model meta api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/meta/) and check the 1-to-1 fields whose related_model is a `BaseProfile` subclass:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.db.models.fields.related import OneToOneRel
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class User(Abs...User):
    # ...

    @cached_property
    def profile(self):
        for f in User._meta.get_fields():
            if isinstance(f, OneToOneRel) and issubclass(f.related_model, BaseProfile):
                try:
                    return getattr(self, f.name)
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    pass
        # no profile found
        return None
```

Comment: Very interesting, thanks a lot. I just thought I can use this code portion to prevent a user from having more than one profile.

Comment: That should not be too much trouble. Instead of returning from the loop, you can collect the profiles, and if there are more than one in the end, raise an error.